# Autocomplete not working with array of values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have read all posts related jQuery 3.3.1 and jQuery-UI 1.12.1 but I couldn't get the solution. This is my code and its not working.

```html
<link href="lib/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ui-widget">
  <span>Enter Language Name: </span><input id="Language">
</div>
<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
  var tech = [
    "Asp",
    "Basic",
    "Java",
    "Php",
    "Typescript",
    "Ruby",
    "Python",
    "Angular"
  ];
  $('#Language').autocomplete({
    data: tech
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `data` property in the `autocomplete()` settings. If you're providing an array of values to use in the control you need to use `source`. I'd suggest reading the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

```js
var tech = [
  "Asp",
  "Basic",
  "Java",
  "Php",
  "Typescript",
  "Ruby",
  "Python",
  "Angular"
];
$('#Language').autocomplete({
  source: tech
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ui-widget">
  <span>Enter Language Name: </span><input id="Language">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```